# How can i call route from laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call route from laravel controller function with parameter and option parameters.
$product_information = route('route', $parameter, '?optionalParameter');

Comment: Use redirect to redirect to a new route.

Comment: i don't want to redirect

Comment: You shouldn't need to call another route then. If still needed, call the related controller method which should be static by nature or make this functionality inside a trait and use traits in all controllers wherever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a `$parameters` array before sending to the 2nd param in the `route()` method this way you can add required and optional params.

```
$parameters = [];

if (isset($optionalParam) && !empty($optionalParam)) {
    $parameters['optional'] = $optionalParam;
}

$url = route('route', $parameters);
```

Comment: but how to call route inside controller function

Comment: and secondly optional parameter always have '?' infront

Comment: @sydlkar you can `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http`  do do requests too.

Comment: ``redirect()->route('route', $parameters);`` should redirect to the route with parameters.

Comment: @OMiShah he don't want a redirect but want to "call route" so [Http client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#main-content) will do

Comment: @syedIkrar if you don't want query param `?`, you can do someting like `$url = route('route'). '/' . $id;` and this will do like `http://your-website/route/1`.